# Switch primary graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst, amd-graphics-card

I currently have two separate AMD graphics cards installed in my PC. 
A HD 7870 and a r9 390. 
I only need one of them at the moment, but I will need the second one, once I get a second monitor. 
The problem is that I can't use the r9 390 because my pc always boots with the 7870 and deactivates the one I would like to use. 
They both show up in the amd control center, but as I said the 390 shows up as deactivated, while the 7870 is the primary one.

I also tried to change it in the BIOS, but I couldn't find any settings that would do this.

I could probably solve this by manually plugging out the card I don't use, but I would rather not do that.

Any other ideas?

Comment: What happens if you physically swap the cards inside the PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary video card is set to a slot.  Sometimes in the BIOS you can change it, but the choices may not be obvious.  Instead of displaying the name of the card it just has PCIEX_1, PXIEX_2, etc or something similiar to that.

If the adjustment isn't in the BIOS you have to physically swap the 2 cards.

Also you can run both video cards in your system at the same time on 1 monitor, and still connect a 2nd monitor anytime you want.  In many cases it boost the performance, and in rare cases you get 90% of both cards.  There should be a small cable to connect them on the back.  This is called a **crossfire** configuration, or SLI in the nvidia world.